# How to avoid recursive error when returning python dict elements in python?

Tags: python

Suppose you want to return elements of a python dictionary as attributes of the class itself, you might implement it as follows:

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        print(self.x)
        self.metadata = {
             "a": 42,
             "b": 1,          
        }
        
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        if item in self.metadata:
            return self.metadata[item]
        else:
            raise KeyError(f"No attribute {item} found.")

test = MyClass()
```

But that implementation creates a recursive error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that in the method `__getattr__` it is checked if some element `item` is in the dict `self.metadata` which is not yet defined! So by getting the attribute `self.metadata` it calls the `__getattr__` method again!

The solution is to check if the `metadata` attribute exists in the first place. So the `__getattr__` method will become

```
def __getattr__(item):
    if "metadata" in self.__dict__ and item in self.metadata:
        return self.metadata[item]
    else:
        raise KeyError(f"No attribute {item} found.")
```

So only if the atribute `metadata` exists in the class it will check if the `item` exists...